# html buttons and dropdown script issue

Tags: html

Hello I have some several issues with my code and I can't find any solution for days now.

**Issue 1:** Brand of vaccine still persists when selecting yes then selecting no.

[image]

**Issue 2:** No submit button in "No" option, and in are you vaccinated options the yes and no selection disappears.

[image]

**Issue 3:** Other dropdown didn't disappear.

[image]

```
<html>
  <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
          function displayForm1(c) {
              if (c.value == "1") {
              document.getElementById("yesformContainer").style.visibility = 'visible';
              document.getElementById("noformContainer").style.visibility = 'hidden';
              } else if (c.value == "2") {
              document.getElementById("yesformContainer").style.visibility = 'hidden';
              document.getElementById("noformContainer").style.visibility = 'visible';
              } else {}
     }
     </script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        function displayForm2(c) {
            if (c.value == "once") {
                document.getElementById("onceboostContainer").style.visibility = 'visible';
                document.getElementById("twiceboostContainer").style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById("noboostContainer").style.visibility = 'hidden';
            } else if (c.value == "twice") {
                document.getElementById("onceboostContainer").style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById("twiceboostContainer").style.visibility = 'visible';
                document.getElementById("noboostContainer").style.visibility = 'hidden';
            } else if (c.value == "none") {
                document.getElementById("onceboostContainer").style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById("twiceboostContainer").style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById("noboostContainer").style.visibility = 'visible';
            } else{}
        }

    </script>
<form id="Personal Information">
<h1>Personal Information</h1>
<label for="name">Name</label> <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>
<h3>Address</h3>
<label for="houseno">House No.</label>  <input type="text" id="houseno" name="houseno">
<label for="street">Street</label>  <input type="text" id="street" name="street">
<label for="brgysubd">Brgy. or Subd.</label> <input type="text" id="brgysubd" name="brgysubd">
<h3>City/Municipality</h3>
<select name="citymun" id="citymuns">
    <option value="nonecity">Select City...</option>
    <option value="Alfonso">Alfonso</option>
    <option value="Amadeo">Amadeo</option>
    <option value="Bacoor">Bacoor</option>
    <option value="Carmona">Carmona</option>
    <option value="Cavite City">Cavite City</option>
    <option value="Dasmariñas">Dasmariñas</option>
    <option value="General Emilio Aguinaldo">General Emilio Aguinaldo</option>
    <option value="GMA">GMA</option>
    <option value="General Trias">General Trias</option>
    <option value="Imus">Imus</option>
    <option value="Indang">Indang</option>
    <option value="Kawit">Kawit</option>
    <option value="Magallanes">Magallanes</option>
    <option value="Maragondon">Maragondon</option>
    <option value="Mendez">Mendez</option>
    <option value="Naic">Naic</option>
    <option value="Noveleta">Noveleta</option>
    <option value="Rosario">Rosario</option>
    <option value="Silang">Silang</option>
    <option value="Tagaytay">Tagaytay</option>
    <option value="Tanza">Tanza</option>
    <option value="Ternate">Ternate</option>
    <option value="Trece Martires">Trece Martires</option>
</select><br>
<br>
<label for="bday">Birthday</label> <input type="date" id="bday" name="bday" min="1900-01-01" max="2022-12-31"><br>
<h3>Contact Number</h3>
<label for="numbercel">Mobile Number</label> <input type="tel" id="contactcel" name="contactcel" pattern="[0]{1}-[1-9]{3}-[0-9]{7}">
<label for="numbertel">Telephone Number</label> <input type="tel" id="contacttel" name="contacttel" pattern="[0]{1}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{7}">
<h3>Vaccination Status</h3>
<p>Are you fully vaccinated?</p>
<label for="yes">Yes</label> <input value="1" type="radio" id="vaccyes" name="question" value="yes" onclick="displayForm1(this)"><br>
<label for="no">No</label> <input value="2" type="radio" id="vaccno" name="question" value="no" onclick="displayForm1(this)"><br>

<div style="visibility:hidden; position:relative" id="yesformContainer">
    <form id="yesform">
       <p>Brand of Vaccine (1st)</p>
<select name="vaccbrand" id="vaccinebrand">
    <option value="nullvac">Select Brand...</option>
    <option value="COVONAX">COVOVAX (Novavax formulation)</option>
    <option value="Comirnaty">Pfizer/BioNTech Comirnaty</option>
    <option value="Spikevax">Moderna Spikevax</option>
    <option value="SputnikLight">Gamaleya Sputnik Light</option>
    <option value="SputnikV">Gamaleya Sputnik V</option>
    <option value="Jcovden">Janssen (Johnson & Johnson) Jcovden</option>
    <option value="Vaxzevria">Oxford/AstraZeneca Vaxzevria</option>
    <option value="Covaxin">Bharat Biotech Covaxin</option>
    <option value="Covilo">Sinopharm (Beijing) Covilo</option>
    <option value="Inactivated">Sinopharm (Wuhan) Inactivated (Vero Cells)</option>
    <option value="CoronaVac">Sinovac CoronaVac</option>
    <option value="nonevac">None</option>
</select>
<p>Brand of Vaccine (2nd)</p>
<select name="vaccbrand" id="vaccinebrand">
    <option value="nullvac">Select Brand...</option>
    <option value="COVONAX">COVOVAX (Novavax formulation)</option>
    <option value="Comirnaty">Pfizer/BioNTech Comirnaty</option>
    <option value="Spikevax">Moderna Spikevax</option>
    <option value="SputnikLight">Gamaleya Sputnik Light</option>
    <option value="SputnikV">Gamaleya Sputnik V</option>
    <option value="Jcovden">Janssen (Johnson & Johnson) Jcovden</option>
    <option value="Vaxzevria">Oxford/AstraZeneca Vaxzevria</option>
    <option value="Covaxin">Bharat Biotech Covaxin</option>
    <option value="Covilo">Sinopharm (Beijing) Covilo</option>
    <option value="Inactivated">Sinopharm (Wuhan) Inactivated (Vero Cells)</option>
    <option value="CoronaVac">Sinovac CoronaVac</option>
    <option value="nonevac">None</option>
</select><br><br>
    </form>
    <p>Are you boostered?</p>
    <label for="once">Once</label> <input value="once" type="radio" id="boostone" name="question" value="once" onclick="displayForm2(this)"><br>
    <label for="twice">Twice</label> <input value="twice" type="radio" id="boosttwo" name="question" value="twice" onclick="displayForm2(this)"><br>
    <label for="noboost">No</label> <input value="noboost" type="radio" id="boostno" name="question" value="noboost" onclick="displayForm2(this)"><br>
        <div style="visibility:hidden; position:relative" id="onceboostContainer">
        <form id="onceboost">
            <p>Brand of Vaccine</p>
<select name="vaccbrand" id="vaccinebrand">
    <option value="nullvac">Select Brand...</option>
    <option value="COVONAX">COVOVAX (Novavax formulation)</option>
    <option value="Comirnaty">Pfizer/BioNTech Comirnaty</option>
    <option value="Spikevax">Moderna Spikevax</option>
    <option value="SputnikLight">Gamaleya Sputnik Light</option>
    <option value="SputnikV">Gamaleya Sputnik V</option>
    <option value="Jcovden">Janssen (Johnson & Johnson) Jcovden</option>
    <option value="Vaxzevria">Oxford/AstraZeneca Vaxzevria</option>
    <option value="Covaxin">Bharat Biotech Covaxin</option>
    <option value="Covilo">Sinopharm (Beijing) Covilo</option>
    <option value="Inactivated">Sinopharm (Wuhan) Inactivated (Vero Cells)</option>
    <option value="CoronaVac">Sinovac CoronaVac</option>
    <option value="nonevac">None</option>
</select><br><br>
<input type="submit">
            </form></div>
        <div style="visibility:hidden; position:relative" id="twiceboostContainer">
        <form id="twiceboost">
            <p>Brand of Vaccine (1st)</p>
            <select name="vaccbrand" id="vaccinebrand">
                <option value="nullvac">Select Brand...</option>
                <option value="COVONAX">COVOVAX (Novavax formulation)</option>
                <option value="Comirnaty">Pfizer/BioNTech Comirnaty</option>
                <option value="Spikevax">Moderna Spikevax</option>
                <option value="SputnikLight">Gamaleya Sputnik Light</option>
                <option value="SputnikV">Gamaleya Sputnik V</option>
                <option value="Jcovden">Janssen (Johnson & Johnson) Jcovden</option>
                <option value="Vaxzevria">Oxford/AstraZeneca Vaxzevria</option>
                <option value="Covaxin">Bharat Biotech Covaxin</option>
                <option value="Covilo">Sinopharm (Beijing) Covilo</option>
                <option value="Inactivated">Sinopharm (Wuhan) Inactivated (Vero Cells)</option>
                <option value="CoronaVac">Sinovac CoronaVac</option>
                <option value="nonevac">None</option>
            </select>
            <p>Brand of Vaccine (2nd)</p>
            <select name="vaccbrand" id="vaccinebrand">
                <option value="nullvac">Select Brand...</option>
                <option value="COVONAX">COVOVAX (Novavax formulation)</option>
                <option value="Comirnaty">Pfizer/BioNTech Comirnaty</option>
                <option value="Spikevax">Moderna Spikevax</option>
                <option value="SputnikLight">Gamaleya Sputnik Light</option>
                <option value="SputnikV">Gamaleya Sputnik V</option>
                <option value="Jcovden">Janssen (Johnson & Johnson) Jcovden</option>
                <option value="Vaxzevria">Oxford/AstraZeneca Vaxzevria</option>
                <option value="Covaxin">Bharat Biotech Covaxin</option>
                <option value="Covilo">Sinopharm (Beijing) Covilo</option>
                <option value="Inactivated">Sinopharm (Wuhan) Inactivated (Vero Cells)</option>
                <option value="CoronaVac">Sinovac CoronaVac</option>
                <option value="nonevac">None</option>
            </select><br><br>
            <input type="submit">
                    </form></div>
            <div style="visibility:hidden;position:relative;top:-110px;margin-top:-110px" id="noboostContainer">
            <form id="noform">
                <input type="submit">
                    </form></div>
</div>
<div style="visibility:hidden;position:relative;top:-110px;margin-top:-110px" id="noformContainer">
    <form id="noform">
        <input type="submit">
        </form>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a mismatch between your option value and your `displayForm2` value.
Your 'no' option looks like this:

```html
<label for="noboost">No</label>
<input value="noboost" type="radio" id="boostno" name="question" value="noboost" onclick="displayForm2(this)"><br>
```

And here is your `displayForm2` function.

```js
function displayForm2(c) {
        if (c.value == "once") {
            document.getElementById("onceboostContainer").style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById("twiceboostContainer").style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.getElementById("noboostContainer").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        } else if (c.value == "twice") {
            document.getElementById("onceboostContainer").style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.getElementById("twiceboostContainer").style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById("noboostContainer").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        } else if (c.value == "none") {
            document.getElementById("onceboostContainer").style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.getElementById("twiceboostContainer").style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.getElementById("noboostContainer").style.visibility = 'visible';
        } else{}
    }
```

As you can see your 'no' option value is `noboost` whereas the value in your `displayForm2` is `none`. So, I changed the value inside your `displayForm2` to `noboost` and it worked perfectly. I also changed the radio input names in booster section to separate it from the fully vaccinated section inputs.
You can check my code snippet here [code-sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-glitter-kmkge4?file=/index.html:779-1728).